# how do i print the value B of the filtered property value A?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, certificate, command-prompt

How do i print another property value within a command that has been filtered?

In the given code below, I've filtered value A of the property value. how do i print the value B of the filtered property value?

```
for /f %g in ('certutil -v -store my^|findstr "Key.Encipherment,.Data.Encipherment.(30)"') do (certutil -v -store my | findstr "Serial.Number")
```

i'm still getting all the serial numbers printed by adding `/f`. the filtering doesn't seems to be working as expected. any help? i'm still new in cmd...

Comment: Your `for` won't run (you'd need `for /f`, see `for /?`). And I doubt the correctness of the `findstr` searchstring. Besides that, I don't understand your question. Please rephrase and show the desired output.

Comment: The question is how do i print the serial number(Value B) of those certificates in certificate store that has been filtered by keyusage values( "Key.Encipherment,.Data.Encipherment.(30) value A)? output should be only serial number

Comment: You need to explain what exactly you're expecting this command to do! If I was to use your command outside of a [tag:for-loop], it would return the following output, `"        Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment (30)"`, _without the enclosing doublequotes (added just to show the preceding space characters)_. Inside the [tag:for-loop], with no provided delimiters or tokens it will use the default first token with the space and tab as delimiters, passing `Key` to the `Do` portion.

Comment: Your `Do` command on the other hand, even slightly improved to `%__AppDir__%certutil.exe -v -store My | %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /I "\<Serial\ Number:\>"` would just return one or more lines like this, `Serial Number: 06328c00ac00628a11cfb6d4aa5d312f5`. There is nothing whatsoever which will link the result of the first command to a serial number and vice versa, as they're all just single lines from the output of a command, _(or in this case two commands)_.

Comment: oh i'm running out of ideas so i though the for loop will work. i am new to this.. how do i  implement it correctly so i can get the desire output?

Comment: You can do that by Opening a Command Prompt window, typing `certutil -v -store my >"%temp%\$_.tmp" && start /w notepad "%temp%\$_.tmp" & del "%temp%\$_.tmp"` and pressin the 'ENTER' key. Then copy the content from your notepad, and paste it, formatted as code, into your question using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61848403/edit) facility.